# iPhone: get image from camera without UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Please help me with my question.

Is there any way to get image from camera without `UIImagePickerController`?

I need to render current image(from camera) into image on my view and update it by timer.
May be `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`? I didn't find any examples.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it easily using `AVCamCaptureManager` and `AVCamRecorder` classes. Apple has a demo program build on its developer site [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112). It is named `AVCam`. In simple words what it does is when you click to open the camera, it calls the classes and methods which are responsible for opening the iPhone's camera and record video or capture audio. It calls the same classes which are called by `UIImagePickerController`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, but I have only 10.6.5 mac os, I can't run this example, it's too complex. Can you help me with an easier example?

Comment: Even I have a Mac OS 10.6.5. And it runs perfectly and its fairly easy as well. I think you're doing something wrong. Make sure you don't try to run that program in your simulator as it wont work there. Build it and Run it in your device it will work perfectly.